# What is the command to list the files of specific extension within the range of file size and with depth of file search?

Tags: command-line, scripts, files, find

I tried using the following command but it is not working.

```
sudo find / -type f -iname "*.ttx" -size +5k 2>/dev/null | grep -E '^/?([^/]+/?){0,3}$'
```

I am using `2>/dev/null` to avoid error messages.

when I use the following command it is perfectly showing the files with specific extension and depth of search. when I am applying the size filter it is not working. please help me out with this.

Thank you.

Comment: The test `-size +5k` finds only files with at least **5*1024+1 = 5121** bytes. Maybe your files have a size between **5000** and **5121** bytes. This is because **k** means **Kibibyte = 2^10 = 1024 byte**.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for this:

sudo find / -type f -iname "*.ttx" -size +5000c -size -6000c 2>/dev/null | grep -E '^/?([^/]+/?){0,3}$'

The above command will list all the files with .ttx extension within the size range of 5Kb to 6Kb with the depth of 3 from /

Thank you.

Comment: I found the command to find file but how do I take input from user for file extension, minimum size, maximum size and depth of search. Is there a way to take all these inputs as command-line input?  Thank you.